# BASH: syntax error near unexpected token `

Tags: linux, bash

I just learned bash fundamentals but now, I have an issue. Following my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
search_db ()
{
    echo "PROVA"
}
search_db
exit
```

Where I'm wrong? 
Sorry for this simple question but I'm a newbie.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is that the full error? Could it be that your file has CRLF EOLs?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that. It works just fine. Does the file have DOS line endings maybe? Does running `dos2unix` on the file help?

Comment: @Biffen Full error: 'cleanup.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token ` 'cleanup.sh: line 9: `search_db ()

Comment: Your script doesn't even have 9 lines! how can you post a question with an error that is completely irrelevant to what you're showing us? btw, as written, your script works fine.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf. Sorry, my mistake. Error line is wrong. Script doesn't work. My server is CentOS 6.6.

Comment: Is the code you posted _exactly_ the script you're running, or are you hiding stuff from us? because, as written, your script works perfectly well.

Comment: No nothing. I run my script with this command: sh -x test.sh. Result is: 'test.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `
'test.sh: line 2: `search_db()

Comment: @RaffaeleCapasso Did you check the EOLs and/or did you try `dos2unix`?

Comment: @Biffen you're a genius!!! My script after conversion, works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not that anyone ever reads the [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) but this is point 1 on there. I really wish that they were shown more prominently...

Comment: This question is a duplicate of so many others, but I can't find any of them. Perhaps some kindhearted hero could flag it...